# What is the logic behind the ordering and numbering of Sappho fragments, and why did it change e.g. from Edmonds to Campbell?

Tags: greek, poetry, sappho

I understand ordering the poems by meter, and perhaps putting those of uncertain meter at the end. However, there are many poems with the same meter, especially Sapphic stanzas (which is probably why it's called Sapphic stanza), so one has to order the poems within meter sections as well. I have also noticed there was a change between the numbering of e.g. Edmonds and that of e.g. Campbell, and in particular that the poem quoted by Longinus and "translated" by Catullus into his `Ille mi par esse deo videtur` is number 2 in Edmonds and number 31 in Campbell, which is particularly annoying since every time I look for this in Campbell I have to browse *n* pages before I find it, whereas in almost every other source I have it is readily found at the beginning. So what is the logic behind the ordering of the poems, and why was the ordering changed over time?